# Why is half of my UV mesh off of the grid, and how do I fix it?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I've got two models, each with their own texture, that I'm trying to combine into one model with one texture so I can mod it into a game. I've tried following tutorials on how to bake textures into one, but when I join the models and look at the UV editor the body of the model is off the grid, like this:

[image]

This makes it really hard to follow tutorials, since all of the ones I've seen have everything nicely located within the grid, and I've tried in Blender and 3DS Max. None of my attempts have resulted in a texture that lines up with the model in the correct way, and I think this has something to do with it. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't match up to begin with. But I do think I know how to fix it. Select all your UVs in the UV Editor and from the *UV menu*, choose **Pack Islands**. This will force all your islands to scale down (evenly) until they are contained within your UV space.

Another useful feature, under the same menu, is the *Constrain to Image Bounds* checkbox. It will prevent any islands or UVs from being dragged outside the UV space.

Comment: @R-800 that worked, thank you!